# Write to a C++ char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a library that exports a `char*` in which I can generate a message and then call send to send the message (over the network). How can I write a very simple message to the exported buffer in the code?

I wrote four different methods to write the message, none of which is ideal:

```
class Lib {
  char msg[100];

public:
  Lib() {
    // nullify the buffer
    msg[0] = 0;
  }

  char* get_buffer() {
    return msg;
  }

  void send() {
    std::cout << "Message is: " << msg << std::endl;
    // nullify the buffer for the next send
    msg[0] = 0;
  }

};

int main () {
  {
    Lib lib;
    char* buf = lib.get_buffer();

    // Method 1 is tedious
    buf[0] = 'H';
    buf[1] = 'e';
    buf[2] = 'l';
    buf[3] = 'l';
    buf[4] = 'o';
    buf[5] = 0;

    lib.send();
  }

  {
    Lib lib;
    char* buf = lib.get_buffer();

    // Method 2 doesn't work
    buf = "Hello";

    lib.send();
  }

  {
    Lib lib;
    char* buf = lib.get_buffer();

    // Method 3 involves a copy
    string str = "Hello";
    str.copy(buf, str.size());

    lib.send();
  }

  {
    Lib lib;
    char* buf = lib.get_buffer();

    // Method 4 involves a copy
    char* c_arr = "Hello";
    std::memcpy(buf, c_arr, 6);

    lib.send();
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
Message is: Hello
Message is: 
Message is: Hello
Message is: Hello
```

The first method seems tedious to me. The second method doesn't work because `buf` then points to a fresh location in memory that contains "Hello". The third and fourth method involve creation of a temporary memory buffer and memory copy.

I would like something similar to `buf = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l','o'};`, but that works only at construction time.

Not to mention that I have one compilation warning each in Method 2 and Method 4 with `g++-7.3`:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Comment: Your warning is saying that you are converting a string literal to `char*`. This is something that isn't supported in c++ anymore. They should only be assigned to `const char*`.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to just make `Lib::msg` be an `std::string`.

Comment: `char* send()` you are not returning anything from that method

Comment: Sorry, changed to `void send()`.

Comment: You are given a buffer. You're going to have to copy data into it at some point to make the buffer useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the `char*` from a library and you do not have any control over that part you will need to copy some data. That is kind of inevitable, when you get the location in memory dictated by the library. Note that the first method is also a copy, just a manual one.
I would work with `std::string` within your end of the code and then copy the memory over to the buffer.
So I guess Method 3 is probably the best one, but I really hope the library provides you with the buffer size as well and you should make sure you do not copy too much into it.